# Generating square wave to be inputted into a MCU

Tags: operational-amplifier, signal-processing, schmitt-trigger

There are signals like below picture inputted to MCU STM32f103:
(Offset DC about 800mV, Vmax = 2.4V, f = 66 Hz)

[image]

I want to change it to a squar wave from 0V to 3.3V being accepted voltage range for my MCU.
How I can implement it? Using a schmitt trigger implemented by an op amp?
Can you please provide me a schematic?

**EDIT:

Based on ChrisStratton`s comment:**     Cost and power do not matter. I am going to obtain frequency of signal by MCU Timer/Counter. In fact my ultimate goal is to have the frequency to calculate speed. One hertz could be an accepted precision and the frequency is less than 1 KHz. Actually the first thing I tried was AC coupling being able to remove DC offset. However, the amplitude was not what I want. To sum up, I need to have a square wave with the same frequency and 0 V to 3.3 V amplitude.

Comment: What properties of the signal do you need to recover?  If timing, with how much precision?  Do you need to sleep to save power?  If the requirement is lenient using the adc and software hysteresis could be an option.  If the leading edge is reliably sharp AC coupling and a blanking time on retrigger could work.  A meaningful answer would require details and goals not presented - do you want universal reliability?  Minimum cost?  Minimum.power?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Cost and power do not matter. I am going to obtain frequency of signal by MCU Timer/Counter. In fact my ultimate goal is to have the frequency to calculate speed. One hertz could be an accepted precision. Actually the first thing I tried was AC coupling being able to remove DC offset. However the amplitude was not what I want. To sum up, I need to have a square wave with the same frequency and 0 V to 3.3 V amplitude.

Comment: No, your application does not require a square wave, it requires *recovering timing*. You could do that with the ADC without further conditioning the signal electrically.  You could for example look for a positive change of a certain amount within a small number of samples.  You could then use that to adjust a software PLL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For standard IO the [STM32F103 datasheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwicvMq0k5vkAhV-UxUIHSM3CEMQFjAAegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fresource%2Fen%2Fdatasheet%2Fstm32f103c8.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0rd6I_7fuhTLdZOoycvGV5) section 5.3.13 says:

- \$ V_{IL(max)} = 0.28 (V_{DD} -2 \ \text V) + 0.8 \ \text V \$. For a 3.3 V supply this is 1.16 V.
- \$ V_{IH(min)} = 0.41 (V_{DD} -2 \ \text V) + 1.3 \ \text V \$. For a 3.3 V supply this is 1.83 V.

> Offset DC about 800mV, Vmax = 2.4V.

```
        0         1         2         3  3.3 V
        |    .    |    .    |    .    |  |     
GPIO:   |           ===.===              |
Signal: |       =================        |
```

Since your signal low < GPIO V<sub>IL</sub> min and your signal high > GPIO V<sub>IH</sub> max I think you can feed your signal straight in.

Additional component count: 0.

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f02zEm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. A comparator with auto-reference adjust.*

The idea here is that C1 will charge to a reference voltage a little higher than the low signal due to the duty-cycle of the signal. R3 helps pull it a little higher but may not be required.

Most comparators have open collector outputs so R1 has been added but the GPIO internal pull-up may suffice.

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, in my circuit there are some conditions that do not conform to MCU logical range and I need to reassure myself. So please consider that I want to convert it to a square wave.

Comment: You need to make that clear in your question to avoid wasting folks' time.

Comment: This is a relatively bad idea unless the behavior of the input is known to be reliably consistent.  Without a solid explanation of the source of the offset it's level cannot be relied upon to stay safely low.

Comment: Sure, but there was nothing in the question to indicate that a stable source was not the case. A comparator will suffer the same problem is the \$ V_{IL(max)} > V_{IH(min)} \$. One could try using a very low-pass filter for the signal and use that as the reference.

Answer (score 2):

a much easier way would be a simple schmitt trigger like you first suggest, you can use an op amp to do it, it just changes in name to a comparator with hysteresis,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBY1G5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Edit: supply voltage would be 0 and 3.3V, the 100K controls the amount of hysteresis, right now its quite low, but should be suitable

Edit2: Changed to non inverting, circuit also simulated here with falstads,

[Falstads Circuit Link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+66+5+50%0Aa+320+208+432+208+8+3.3+0+1000000+1.65+0.7814941196820285+100000%0Aw+432+208+432+272+0%0Ar+432+272+288+272+0+100000%0Aw+288+224+320+224+0%0Aw+288+224+288+272+0%0Ar+320+192+320+128+0+10000%0Ar+288+272+208+272+0+10000%0AO+432+208+480+208+0%0AR+320+128+320+96+0+0+40+3.3+0+0+0.5%0AR+208+272+144+272+0+1+10+0.8+1.6+0+0.5%0Ar+272+192+272+128+0+10000%0Ag+272+128+272+112+0%0Aw+272+192+320+192+0%0Ao+7+64+0+4098+5+0.1+0+1%0Ao+9+64+0+4099+5+0.00009765625+1+2+9+3%0A)

Comment: The TL081 requires a minimum supply of 10V. Also, opamps can be slow when used as comparators. Better to use an actual comparator instead. Many operate at 3.3V, and some of them have built-in hysteresis. And your circuit inverts the signal, which may or may not matter to the OP.

Comment: @Reroute I simulated your schematic by means of Multisim but i get only a constant DC voltage in output.

Comment: @DaveTweed can you please explain your idea?

Comment: @Pana: What do you mean? You can buy ICs called "opamps" and you can buy ICs called "comparators" -- I'm saying you want the latter, not the former. But the point is moot, given [@Transistor's analysis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/454426/11683).

Comment: I was not successful in simulating it again. Is it because I use OP07CD instead of OA1 TL081 in my simulation?

Comment: the OP07 is really not a good op amp for low voltage signals, might I suggest the MCP6002, the OP07's output can only swing about 2V away from its supply rails so at 3.3V supply, it cannot control its output at all, The TL081 was just the default op amp model this site uses.

Comment: OP07C ELECTRICAL CHARACTERISTICS: Output Voltage Swing for RL ≥ 10 kΩ, minimum ±12.0V. what does it mean (Vs = ±15 V)? Does not it mean I can use Vcc = 5 and Vee = 0 to have 3.3V at output?

Comment: it means that with a supply of +-15V, it can only output up to +-12V, and is saturated there unable to go any closer to its supply rails, op amps that can output very close to there supply rails are generally reffered to as "Rail to Rail Output", equally these devices can only respond to voltages within a certain range, sometimes called "Common mode input", outside of this range they may misbehave, again some op amps have a "Rail to Rail Input" and some that can handle input voltages up to 3 times the supply voltage, but those higher than supply ones are rare.

Answer (score 1):

According to the valuable answers and comments, including *Transistor*'s ones, I achieved to figure out my issue by means of LM2903P comparator. This is the schematic having enabled me to tackle it:

[image]

and this is the output I got:

[image]

Hoping help somebody!